# Display current speed in OsmAnd

Tags: navigation, osmand

I use OsmAnd when riding my bicycle.

I would like it to display my current speed in a corner of the screen or somewhere similar.

It should not interfere with normal use of OsmAnd, in particular it should not be a different screen.

Is there a way to do this in OsmAnd, via an option or plugin or custom fork or anything?

Answer (score 5):

In OsmAnd:

- Open the navigation drawer (swipe from left or bottom left button)
- “Configure screen” (Gear icon)
- “Right panel” should have a line for “Speed”, tick that.

The speed will be shown, somewhat small, in the top right list. I think standard is to show only the number of satellites, but there are a few items that can be shown there.

Eta:
I also set “Trasparent skin” at the bottom of the “Configure screen” list. Makes the speed &c. a bit less obtrusive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an "overlay" like e.g. [Ulysse Speedometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.binarytoys.speedometer), [Map Speedometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Map.Speedometer), [GPS HUD Speedometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ascendapps.aaspeedometer), [DigiHUD Speedometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mrchops.android.digihud), or [Navigation Speedometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Map.Speedometer):

[image: DigiHUD as map overlay] [image: Ulysse]
<sup>*DigiHUD* and *Ulysse* as map overlays (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

Though above screenshots are not from *OsmAnd*, the overlays work the same there :)